# How to add shipping rate according to weight?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, csv, table-rates

Actually i trying to add shipping charges according to weight.i didn't use any code i did it through admin->sales->shipping method->table rate->import csv.but i facing problem bcoz its not taken shipping according to weight.it calculate to quantity of the product into cart.so what should i do for this?
I attach screenshots here.
[image]

- i set weight as a numeric value 5kg to 5 and make shipping charge 100.but its not working.
- i did'nt add currency code in shipping rate
- it showing in frontend.actually shipping charges not taken according to weight it take shipping charge per item added in the cart while i select weight vs destination and export csv.but still its not working.

[image]

Comment: i didn't found any solution thr.if anyone have the solution plz help me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento SE, feel free to check out this post on how to ask a question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . 
Please provide more information such as **what have you tried so far?, what config did you try? what code did you write?** so we can help you fixing your problem.

Comment: Actually i trying to add shipping charges according to weight.i didn't use any code i did it through admin->sales->shipping method->table rate->import csv.but i facing problem bcoz its not taken shipping according to weight.it calculate to quantity of the product into cart.so what should i do for this?

Comment: if tablerates not working for you as quantity make it mess up use Owebia shipping module (https://github.com/owebia/magento1-module-shipping-free) or https://marketplace.magento.com/owebia-owebia-shipping-2.html. https://owebia.com/os2/en/doc  I have tested it amazing for custom shipping calculation .

Comment: Remember to change the 'scope' up the top left if you don't see the import button (as it is missing in the screenshot of this question as well).

Answer (score 1):

You should use table Rates shipping method, there you can define shipping rates slabs as per destination, weight and price.

Go to :

> System-> configurations->Sales->Shipping Methods

Choose Tablerates shipping method and prepare csv :
check guide here : https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/shipping/table-rates.html

Comment: i did it...but its not working.i set weight as a numeric value 5kg to 5 and make shipping charge 50.but its not working.

Comment: you have to follow the specific format, 2ndly you should not add currency code in shipping price.

Comment: i did'nt add currency code in shipping rate.

Comment: does it show shipping method on frontend ? also make sure rates are updated on website level check this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Wns49SCQp8

Comment: yes it showing in frontend.actually shipping charges not taken according to weight it take shipping charge per item added in the cart while i select weight vs destination and export csv.but still its not working.

Comment: Then you are viewing flat rate, because in flat rate shipping method there are options per order base or per item base

Comment: @ShilpiVarshney, did you check the video link shared in comment this will help you how to create , upload and configure Tablerates shipping

Comment: i checked.but facing same issue.